# Asking to be included in high-level conversations about my project

Tags: work-environment, manager

Background:

I recently graduated from university and started as an entry-level developer at a tech company. My job is focused entirely around one, fairly large project. In terms of knowing the codebase, I am the second-most expert.

I have several managers/superiors who 'own' my project and make high-level decisions on new features and the overall direction for the project. Obviously, this is all very standard stuff.

The actual question:

Frequently, I hear my managers openly discussing in the office about the project. I would like to be included in these conversations, because I feel that I can make valuable contributions to them.

How can I make this happen?

The way I see it, I have a few options:

- Attempt to join the conversation after it starts
- At another time, formally ask to be included in future discussions.
- Do nothing and accept that it is not part of my responsibilities

Comment: Is it a technical or non-technical managers who gather to discuss further project improvement? And are those discussions (per your knowledge) technical or not? Do you have any idea what's discussed there, so you can know that you'll be able to contribute and how?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like most experiences when you are new to the workplace.  Don't take it as an insult, this happens to most people when they come to a new company.  They are trying to get to know you and you are trying to get to know them, after a while you'll feel more comfortable about jumping into those conversations.

Few things to consider for the time being:

- You could jump into the conversation saying something like, "Hi (name), I couldn't help but overhear you were talking about XXXX. I was just working on that this morning, I came to the conclusion it would probably be best to do XXXX for the reason XXXX."
- You could use the same approach as I just mentioned, and wait until another time, to ask the person, as well.

  - it's always good to to add something like, "I couldn't help but overhear", when you are interrupting.  People don't always take kindly to people eavesdropping on their conversations.

I wouldn't ask to be included into future discussions, *until* you feel you have made a good impression to your bosses on the subject.  In other words, once you get into a conversation and prove you know what you are talking about, then I would ask and say, "is there another scheduled meeting on (topic), if so, could you include me on the invite?"  ***Only ask to be included in future meetings***, if you just hear someone talking to someone else in their office or in their cube, informally, then just let it go.  That happens all the time, you don't need to be a part of every conversation.

You can take the approach of doing nothing, but eventually, if you stay on the project long enough, they will begin to trust you and you'll be apart of those conversations.

Comment: To ad to this, ideally they will automatically start including you in such conversations automatically *because you're actually adding value to them*. If you're not, you may want to consider not interrupting the conversations anymore.